Написание кода в Unreal Engine : открепление одного компонента от другого
В описании для класса в UE5.41 есть такие строчки:
BP_Master_Pickup_ Throw
Throw
Sphere
и т.д.
Мне нужно открепить Sphere от Throw, чтобы они были на одном уровне. Не получается мышью это сделать - они меняются местами, но все равно кто-то становится подуровнем другого. Как поступить?

Вроде надо зареперентить (мышкой прикрепить элемент к другому) к элементу выше Throw. То есть к первому Throw, тогда Throw Sphere будут на одном уровне.

а что такое «зареперентить к чему-то»?

Прошу прощения, но тоже не знаю значения слова "зареперентить".

Parent - родитель. Re-parent - поменять родителя. За-re-parent - произвести процесс смены родителя. Как-то так

Спасибо. Ну правильно же, Parentм - родитель.

Только это ничего не меняет. Выше стоит только название самого класса, который редактируется, туда не влезешь. А указанные компоненты чередуются на уровне родителя, а на одном уровне не становятся.
